# why value of i is showing undefined when output of the below code is obtained

Tags: javascript, callback

```js
let i = 0;

const g = (i, callback) => {
  if (i < 100) {
    callback(i)
    i++;
    g(i, callback)
  } else return
}

const k = (i) => {
  setTimeout((i) => {
    console.log('hi' + i);
  }, i * 1000);
}
g(i, k);
```

This is the code which uses callback to print hi concatenated by the value of i at an interval of 1 second for 100 times. i am not able to identify where it is going wrong .It will be very greatful if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: You are shadowing the `i` passed into the function `k` with the parameter of the callback to `setTimeout` and never assigning a value to it., so  `(i) => { console.log('hi' + i); }` should be `() => { console.log('hi' + i); }` or alternatively you should pass it in `setTimeout((i) => { console.log('hi' + i); }, i * 1000, i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i` inside the function passed to `setTimeout` shadows the one `k` accepts as argument. So to correct a snippet you just need to remove callback's argument:

```js
let i = 0;

const g = (i, callback) => {
  if (i < 100) {
    callback(i)
    i++;
    g(i, callback)
  } else return
}

const k = (i) => {
  setTimeout(() => { // <------ I removed `i` here
    console.log('hi' + i);
  }, i * 1000);
}
g(i, k);
```

Comment: You can also use the third and later parameters of `setTimeout` to pass arguments to the callback that will be executed: `setTimeout((i) => { console.log('hi' + i); }, i * 1000, i)`